# Sitewide Google Optimize redirect test

Tags: ab-testing, google-experiments, google-optimize

I have a website www.website.com and we build the same website on another system shop.website.com. We want to test if the new system converts so we thought to set up a google optimize. Is there a way to redirect all the sublink? Something like www.website.com/* to shop.website.com/* as the structure is exactly the same. So if people go to www.website.com/page3 it will go shop.website.com/page3. We have more than 700 pages so doing 700 different redirect experiment it's basically impossible. I read every guide article and internet related forum around but I couldn't find an easy way. Any help?

I'll be extremely grateful.